# Bintray's JCenter not in Sync After publishing the file to Bintray

Tags: bintray, jcenter

I have uploaded my library to jcenter successfully. I received the mail that my package has included to jcenter but I'm unable to use my package by adding `compile 'com.opg.sdk:opgsdk_lite:1.0.0` to another project.

Mail from jcenter: Your request to include your package /onepoint/OPGSDKLite/OPGSDK_Lite_V1.6 in Bintray's JCenter has been approved.

I'm also unable to see my package in http://jcenter.bintray.com/

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for submitting this issue.

Please note that we can see your package (https://bintray.com/onepointglobal/OpgsdkLiteAndroid/OPGSDKLite) under JCenter (http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/opg/sdk/opgsdk_lite/).

Can you please let us know if you still experiencing any issues?

Looking forward to your reply.

Yonatan Brand

Comment: Thanks  Brand for replying,
Actually I have deleted my organisation and created new repository with out organisation than I have uploaded the library to this new repository . Now its showing into "http://jcenter.bintray/com" but with organisation name it  was not working.

Comment: Hi Neeraj, 

Thank you for the reply. As we understand the issue is now resolved. 

Regardless, we would like to add that we do recommend to create an organization and not to host your packages under your own profile. This is since you miss a lot of features such as having other people in your organization that can handle the packages. 

If you would like to change this, please make sure to contact us in support@jfrog.com and we will instruct you and make sure you will be able to host your packages under the organization. 

We hope this clarifies. 

Best Regards, 
Yonatan Brand.